# How was Angel Dust able to successfully fight Colossus?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool, deadpool-2016

In 2016's *Deadpool*, Colossus has two main super-fights.

When Deadpool fights Colossus, Colossus' skin acts like solid metal and Deadpool is unable to harm or even noticeably move him.

However, when Angel Dust fights Colossus, his skin acts like normal human skin, to some degree. Angel Dust is even able to choke him with a strip of metal.

I know that Angel Dust is significantly stronger than Deadpool, but why is Colossus affected in a normal-ish manner when fighting her? Shouldn't she just dent him? And how was the metal strong enough to choke him?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Colossus's mutation is typically described as being able to turn his skin into something called ["organic metal"](http://powerlisting.wikia.com/wiki/Organic_Metal_Skin). That is, the skin is still made up of individual skin cells, but *each cell* has metallic properties. (In this case, supposedly something similar to osmium, IIRC).

That means that, given sufficient strength to distort the metallic skin cells, it will react just like normal skin. The individual cells may dent, but collectively, they'll be elastic, returning to their usual shape once the force is removed.

Angel Dust has the level of strength needed to do this. When she punches Colossus, she's able to force his metallic skin cells to distort; in theory she could even "bruise" or "scar" his skin if she were powerful enough. When she uses the steel girder on his throat, she is compressing his metal skin against his windpipe exactly like normal skin would, and there's nothing special about his *internal* organs, so he begins to choke.

Comment: He also mentions he is uncomfortable fighting/hitting women.

Comment: @Recycle true, he was way holding back